# vim: launch command after load plugins

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

with vim, I can launch a command when vim is open, example: open vim and create a split

```
vim +sp
```

I use vim-fugitive plugin, is I use

```
vim +Gstatus
```

I get

```
E492: No es una orden del editor: Gstatus
```

maybe because fugitive not are loaded when vim launch `Gstatus`

when I launch the vim from terminal, how I can execute a command after the load of plugins ?

In particular, How I can launch vim from terminal with `Gstatus` preloaded.

Answer (score 5):

The answer your general question is contained in `:help startup`.  Here are some relevant parts:

```
3. Execute Ex commands, from environment variables and/or files
...
      *VIMINIT* *.vimrc* *_vimrc* *EXINIT* *.exrc* *_exrc* *$MYVIMRC*
     c. Four places are searched for initializations.  The first that exists
    is used, the others are ignored.  ...
    -  The user vimrc file(s):
            "$HOME/.vimrc"  (for Unix and OS/2) (*)
...
            "$HOME/_vimrc"  (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
            "$VIM/_vimrc"   (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
...
4. Load the plugin scripts.                 *load-plugins*
    This does the same as the command: >
        :runtime! plugin/**/*.vim
...
8. Perform GUI initializations
    Only when starting "gvim", the GUI initializations will be done.  See
    |gui-init|.
...
12. Execute startup commands
    If a "-t" flag was given to Vim, the tag is jumped to.
    The commands given with the |-c| and |+cmd| arguments are executed.
    The starting flag is reset, has("vim_starting") will now return zero.
    If the 'insertmode' option is set, Insert mode is entered.
    The |VimEnter| autocommands are executed.
```

It is sort of a cheat, and will not work with vim in a terminal, but you can put commands in your gvimrc file and they will be run after all the plugins are loaded.  More reliable, as @Peter Rincker suggested in the comments after his answer, is to use a `VimEnter` autocommand.

For your specific question, fugitive uses a `VimEnter` autocommand, defined in its plugin file, to define `:Gstatus` and other commands.  If you want to do `:Gstatus` automatically, you should use a similar autocommand and make sure it is defined after fugitive's, so that yours will be executed after fugitive's.  For example, put this line (untested) in `~/.vim/after/plugin/myfugitive.vim` or some such:

```
:au VimEnter * if exists(':Gstatus') | Gstatus | endif
```

That will test whether the command has been defined; if so, it will invoke the command.

Comment: Thanks for providing an Answer, It;s working flawlessly with vDebug for Vim :)

Answer (score 3):

`:Gstatus` is a buffer specific command. So the command will not exist unless you open a file in the repo. Read more here: `:h :command-buffer` and the first paragraph here `:h fugitive-commands`

Examples:

```
vim -c Gstatus <filename>  # -c "cmd" will be executed after the first file has been read.
vim +Gstatus <filename>    # +command is a shortcut for `-c command`
vim .git/index             # opens :Gstatus without a file (answer by derenio)
```

Comment: if I open `vim` without files (in a git repo), I can use the `Gstatus` command.

Comment: This is because fugitive uses the `VimEnter` autocmd to sniff for a `.git` directory and possibly attach fugitive commands. `VimEnter` fires after all the startup stuff including `-c cmd`'s. You can play nicely with this by doing `vim -c "autocmd VimEnter * Gstatus"` See `:h VimEnter` for more information.

Comment: @PeterRincker:  Maybe we have different versions of the fugitive plugin, but mine uses a `BufNewFile,BufReadPost` autocommand to define `:Gstatus` and other commands.  After `:verbose command Gstatus` I knew to look in `fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim`.  Then it took some work to figure out the sequence:  the autocommand calls `s:Detect()` which decides whether to call `s:commands()`, which defines all the commands in the List `s:command`.

Comment: @benjifisher It also executes via the `VimEnter` autocmd. Look inside [plugin/fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/plugin/fugitive.vim#L200)

Comment: @PeterRincker:  OK, I see it now, and that is the one that triggers when you start vim without a filename.

Answer (score 1):

Fugitive automatically runs `:Gstatus` after opening the `.git/index` file of your target repository. Instead of trying to manually run `Gstatus`, use this command:

```
vim .git/index
```

*Note:*
If you like to invoke `Gstatus` as the OP suggested (`$ vim +Gstatus`), you can add following to your `vimrc`:

```
command Gstatus edit .git/index
```

**However**, this works only if you are in the root directory of your git repository.

The fugitive plugin defines the `Gstatus` command with `command!`. This means fugitive silently overwrites this command definition.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could consider is setting up an alias such as

```
alias gst='vim $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/index'
```

this will open :Gstatus without a file (as suggested by derenio) however you do not need to be in git's root directory for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

All of the suggestions regarding opening the `.git/index` file are essentially correct, but one needs to be careful regarding the actual location of that file.  Technically the correctest invocation is:

```sh
alias gst='vim $(git rev-parse --git-path index)'
```

A sufficient invocation is:

```sh
alias gst='vim $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/index'
```

This properly accounts for things like worktrees where the index is stored in a subdirectory of the root repository (not in the worktree).

My preferred method of doing this is through a `git` alias defined as follows:

```
[alias]
    vim = "!_(){ cd ${GIT_PREFIX}; \
        vim '+ped ${GIT_DIR}/index' '+winc P' '+setl fdl=1' ${1:+'+winc p'} $* \
    ;};_"
```

The purpose of the `cd ${GIT_PREFIX}` is because aliases are always run from the base of the repository, so this ensures we return to the directory we called it from.  The `ped ${GIT_DIR}/index` loads the index in the preview window (which is what `:Gstatus` does), and the `winc P` sets focus to the preview window.  The `setl fdl=1` is just to undo folds because I have them enabled by default but don't want them in the status window.

The `${1:+'winc p'} $*` means that any arguments passed to `git vim` are then also passed to `vim`, and I am assuming that if there are arguments one of them is likely to be a file that we want to interact with, so the `winc p` returns focus to the previous window (the first loaded file) only if there are arguments.

Note that you could replace the `'+ped ${GIT_DIR}/index'` with `\"+ped $(git rev-parse --git-path index)\"` if you want to be completely future proof.